# Laravel project uses .env variable from another project

Tags: curl, laravel-5

I have 2 Laravel 5 projects (Project A & Project B) running on WAMP.

Database config for both projects is in .env file.

Everything works fine in both projects however when I make request from Project A to Project B using curl or file_get_contents().

Project B uses database config from .env file of project A.

Correct DB config is loaded if instead of using .env file, I set database config directly in config/database.php file.

Anyone knows why this is happening? and how to avoid this?

Comment: Did you check the sql  select_db connect parameters in the code?

Comment: Everything seems fine in MySqlConnector.php. The issue must be in vlucas/phpdotenv library as it works fine if we don't use .env variable.

Comment: so project a and b have there own laravel instance, right? Try `composer dump-autoload`. Maybe there is a wrong path stored somewhere. Did you copy project B from project A? have you made changes to your /vendor/composer/autoload_real.php file? (**<-- never do that! use `composer dump-autoload` for that**)

Comment: yes both have different instances and not copied from each other, haven't touched autoload_real and did dump-autoload as well..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data base configuration in .env file and in the database file 
and make it not like the other project

```
DB_HOST_SITE=my_database
DB_DATABASE_SITE=my_database
DB_USERNAME_SITE=root
DB_PASSWORD_SITE=password
```

and in database.php file

```
'host'      => env('DB_HOST_SITE', 'localhost'),
'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_SITE', ''),
'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME_SITE', ''),
'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD_SITE', ''),
```

Answer (score 0):

you need set .env DB_{tag}_DATABASE=database_name,Set multiple groups of connections on database.php

model specify the connection {tag}.

this is  system cache for .env.